# Problem with data sorting, sortBy function

Tags: laravel, sorting

Sorry, maybe dumb question, but I have problem with sorting result, I just want sort result by updated_at->data, descending, so the newest records on top

```
public function boostsRequest()
{
    $boosts = Cache::remember('boosts_all', 30, function () {
        $raw = Boost::where('status', 3)->where('hidden', false)->with('screenshot')->get();

        $raw->transform(function ($boost) {
            return [
                'currentdivision' => $boost->currentdivision,
                'desireddivision' => $boost->desireddivision,
                'wins' => $boost->wins,
                'type' => $boost->type,
                'screenshot' => optional($boost->screenshot)->url,
                'updated_at' => $boost->updated_at,
            ];
        });

        $raw = $raw->sortBy(function ($boost) {
            return strtotime($boost->updated_at->date);
        });            

        return $raw;
    });

    return $boosts;
}
```

Normally, the result of a function call is a JSON table filled with objects with the following structure:

`{"currentdivision":"12","desireddivision":"16","wins":null,"type":"division","screenshot":"https:\/\/ucarecdn.com\/86c6d345-1a7f-4af4-8005-175ee235ccd8\/","updated_at":{"date":"2016-11-03 11:11:26.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}`

I want to have a table of objects sorted by the field `updated_at-> date`, descending, so recently updated objects as first

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? Do you get an error? Or is the sorting not working?

Comment: Just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

the updated_at value is not an object, just delete the `->date` part, only this code is needed.

```php
return strtotime($boost->updated_at);
```

tip: sometimes when we doubt about how a value is represented or how a php function behave on a table record, we can use tinker :D.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the collection by updated time in the eloquent request:

```
$raw = Boost::where('status', 3)->where('hidden', false)->with('screenshot')->orderBy('updated_at')->get();
```

Of the `updated_at` value, you are sure it exists in the database. No closure needed.